# How to use a multi-value parameters in report groupings

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I am building a new report that contains Location (ex. California, New York, Texas..), Department (ex. Finance, Enrollment, Claims..) which is setup to be a multi-value parameters.  I was able to use 1 parameter in report row grouping, but i'm not able to use both location and department multivalue parameter in row grouping.  Is this scenario possible in SSRS?

Comment: Why include a parameter if you are just going to select all?

Comment: whether you need to use  Location as parent row grouping and Department As child Row grouping?

Comment: The main ideia is that when the report runs i don't want all the location group to show. I want to show the location group based on location parameter only.  I was able to trigger it with one location, but once i selected multiple location the report shows blank.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your parameters are labelled ParamDepartment and ParamLocation, 
you need to modify the sql dataset for the tablix to include at the end (after the group by clause):

HAVING (tbl_xyz.Location IN (@ParamLocation)) AND (tbl_xyz.Department IN (@ParamDepartment))